# Using access token from .net client library in JavaScript

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to upload videos to a YouTube channel using the JavaScript client library using the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#auth).

However, my access and refresh tokens were gained using the .net library as I will need to use the elsewhere in .net code. I want to be able to instantiate the JavaScript library with those access tokens.  The reason being that the JavaScript upload sequence is a lot nicer as you can have a progress bar etc.

Comment: Have you tried using [gapi.auth.setToken](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsetToken)?

Comment: Yes, that bit now seems to be working except that video upload isn't working in firefox, yet it is in chrome.  I'm getting a "cross-origin request blocked" error in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to use gapi.auth.setToken